# Uploading Multiple Documents To a List Item sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Is there a way we can enable (out of the box )Uploading Multiple Documents To a List Item sharepoint 2010 ?

cheers

Comment: means you want to multiple document functionality on `SPList` like attachments?

Comment: Hi

thanks for your reply. 

yes . to attach  multiple files in one go. do u have any id how to do it ? 

txn

Comment: there are no way on `OOTB`.you can add multiple attachment on specific listitem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way OOTB you can attach multiple documents to a list item . 
I have done it problematically using grid view where i upload the multiple documents to file server folder and maintain the reference to the folders in SharePoint List . The folder contains all the files uploaded at one go .
There should be some telerik control as well to achieve this .

Comment: http://tv.telerik.com/watch/silverlight/video/telerik-silverlight-controls-and-sharepoint-2010-part-5

Answer (score 0):

Yes,You can add multiple attachments for a list item , you just need to add one after the other.

if you are asking to attach multiple documents at once to a list item then my answers is NO.

Answer (score -1):

Open it in datasheet view.

Click on the attachment column.

VOILA :)